# slf4j-jdk14 logger ignores level configuration

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, java.util.logging

I use slf4j with the java.util logger

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.36</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.36</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

For configuration I use a `logging.properties` file with the following content:

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level=ALL
```

But it only prints INFO messages (and above) but no FINE messages.
The configuration seems to work in general because I can set the log format without any problems. Only the level seems to be ignored.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that I have to set the level for the handlers as well.

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level=ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=ALL
```

It seems that by default handlers only handle INFO logs.
Now it works.